# Solution of trig equation $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to do this equation

$$\sin x + \cos x =\sqrt 2$$

If I square both sides, it becomes

$$(\sin x)^2 + (\cos x)^2 = 2$$

But isn't $(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2= 1$ (Pythagorean theorem)?

It should be $$(\sin x)^2 + (\cos x )^2 + 2 \sin x \cos x = 2.$$

But I don't know where the $2 \sin x\cos x$ comes from.

Which trig identity is it? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: $(\sin x + \cos x)^2\neq (\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2$

Comment: Expand $(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin x+\cos x)$. You will then see where the $2\sin x\cos x$ comes from.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! ive noticed my mistake

Comment: Hint to solve the problem: $ \dfrac{ \sin x} {\sqrt2} + \dfrac {\cos x}{ \sqrt 2} = \sin (x + \dfrac \pi 4)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you square both sides, the algebraic identity $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ gives you

$$\sin^2(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)=2$$
now using Pythagoras and the double angle identity for $\sin$ gives
$$1+\sin(2x)=2$$
or 
$$\sin(2x)=1$$
can you take it from here?

---

Another way is to use the $\tan(x/2)$ substituition [(Weierstrass Substituion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to obtain the polynomial equation
$$\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: yep. thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $f(x)= a\sin x+b\cos x$ then you can write it in a form $$f(x) = A\sin(x+\varphi)$$ where $A =\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan \varphi = {b\over a}$

---

In your case $a=b=1$ so $A= \sqrt{2}$ and $\tan \varphi = 1 \implies \varphi = {\pi \over 4}$

Comment: Formula of the added angle :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\require{cancel} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}$$
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}4)\sin(x)+\sin(\frac{\pi}4) \cos(x)=1$$
Using the following identity:
$$\sin(A\pm B)=\cos(B)\sin(A)\pm\cos(A)\sin(B)$$
Therefore:
$$\sin(x+\frac{\pi}4)=1$$
Taking the sine inverse of both sides:

### Sine Inverse

$$\sin^{-1}(\mathbf{\frac{opp}{hyp}}) = \mathbf{angle}$$
Therefore, we can conjecture:
$$\cancel{\sin^{-1}}(\cancel{\sin}(\mathbf{angle}))=\sin^{-1}(\mathbf{\frac{opp}{hyp}}) $$
$$\mathbf{ang} = \sin^{-1}(\mathbf{\frac{opp}{hyp}})$$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x+\frac{\pi}4))=\sin^{-1}(1)$$
$$x+\frac{\pi}4=\frac{\pi}2$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}4$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x=\sqrt2-\cos x$$ and by squaring

$$1-\cos^2x=2-2\sqrt2\cos x+\cos^2x.$$

Solving the quadratic equation we get a single solution

$$\cos x=\frac1{\sqrt2},$$ and from the initial equation, $$\sin x=\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$